# How can i handle marker tap events on windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a GPS tracking application on Windows Phone 8.

I have a map that contains markers which show the location of vehicles.

When I tap any marker I can select the marker and draw a circle image.

When I tap(touch) any point on map, I need to make invisible my selectedMarker image but I cannot get this to work.

I tries mouse leave, lostfocus but neither seemed to work.

```
void ff_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedMarkerLayer = new MapLayer();
    var selectedMarkerPin = new MapOverlay();
    Image selectedMarker = new Image();
    Pushpin pushpin = new Pushpin();
    BitmapImage content = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Assets/Markers/selected.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    selectedMarkerPin.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(39.9207, 32.8539);
    //pushpin.GeoCoordinate.Latitude = 39.9207;
    //pushpin.GeoCoordinate.Longitude = 32.8539;
    selectedMarker.Source = content;
    pushpin.Content = selectedMarker;

    selectedMarkerPin.Content = selectedMarker;
    selectedMarkerLayer.Add(selectedMarkerPin);
    myMap.Layers.Add(selectedMarkerLayer); // markera 
    //selectedMarker.LostMouseCapture += selectedMarker_LostMouseCapture;

    selectedMarker.MouseLeave += selectedMarker_MouseLeave;
    // selectedMarker.LostFocus += selectedMarker_LostFocus;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try `Lost_Focus` event.